# Command Prompt working directory changes after using 'edit' command

Tags: windows, command-line, editing

When I close a file after I have opened it using the edit command, my working directory changes to something funky. Here is what I did:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\josh> edit test.txt
```

I then type 'hello world' in the file, saved the file, and closed it. My working directory now looks like this:

```
C:\DOCUME~1\JO~1>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this may belong on superuser.com as it's not really programming related. When you ask your question there, you might want to add what version of windows you';re using (i.e., do you REALLY mean ms-dos as in WIndows 95/98, or Command in XP/Vista?). I'd suggest checking out Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it's a bug: [Running EDIT Tool Switches Directory Listing to 8.3 Format](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=225126)

> To restore the long file name format directory listing, type cd \ or type cd.. back past the folder being displayed in 8.3 format.

Answer (score 1):

The EDIT command is not changing your directory, rather it's just displaying the same directory in 8.3 notation.

- C:\Documents and Settings\ == C:\DOCUME~1\
- C:\Program Files\ == C:\PROGRA~1\

It's nothing to be concerned about, it's just a holdover from the old days because EDIT.COM is an old 16-bit application.

Comment: To be specific, edit.com runs in the 16-bit virtual machine, which is probably changing the working directory for that program's benefit.